# exoplayer notification manager doesn't show seekbar thumb

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exoplayer

i'm using exo player notification manager to display my song media playback notification , but unfortunately seekbar thumb , current position and max duration not showing , all i get now is just that progressbar nothing else.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cfkS.jpg%60)

here's my foreground service that i use to start notification

```
public class audioPlayerService extends Service {
private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private PlayerNotificationManager playerNotificationManager;
private MediaSessionCompat mediaSession;
private CacheDataSource.Factory factory;
private DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory;
private Bitmap icon;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    final Context context = this;

    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();

    dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)));
    factory = new CacheDataSource.Factory().setCache(downloadUtil.getCache(context))
            .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory);

    playerNotificationManager = new PlayerNotificationManager.Builder(context, 151,
            context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setChannelNameResourceId(R.string.app_name)
            .setChannelImportance(IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            .setMediaDescriptionAdapter(new PlayerNotificationManager.MediaDescriptionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public CharSequence getCurrentContentTitle(Player player) {
                    return player.getCurrentMediaItem().mediaMetadata.displayTitle;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player) {
                    return null;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public CharSequence getCurrentContentText(Player player) {
                    return player.getCurrentMediaItem().mediaMetadata.artist;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public Bitmap getCurrentLargeIcon(Player player, PlayerNotificationManager.BitmapCallback callback) {
                    if (icon == null) {
                        icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                R.drawable.logo);
                    }
                    Glide.with(context)
                            .asBitmap()
                            .load(player.getCurrentMediaItem().mediaMetadata.artworkUri)
                            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                                    icon=resource;
                                    callback.onBitmap(resource);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {

                                }
                            });
                    return icon;
                }

            }).setNotificationListener(new PlayerNotificationManager.NotificationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNotificationCancelled(int notificationId, boolean dismissedByUser) {
                    stopSelf();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNotificationPosted(int notificationId, Notification notification, boolean ongoing) {
                    if (ongoing) {
                        // Here Audio is playing, so we need to make sure the service will not get destroyed by calling startForeground.
                        startForeground(notificationId, notification);
                    } else {
                        //Here audio has stopped playing, so we can make notification dismissible on swipe.
                        stopForeground(false);
                    }
                }
            })
            .build();

    playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
    playerNotificationManager.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
    playerNotificationManager.setUseNextAction(false);
    playerNotificationManager.setUsePreviousAction(false);
    playerNotificationManager.setUseNextActionInCompactView(false);
    playerNotificationManager.setUsePreviousActionInCompactView(false);
    playerNotificationManager.setUseChronometer(true);


    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
    mediaSession.setActive(true);

    MediaSessionConnector mediaSessionConnector =
            new MediaSessionConnector(mediaSession);
    mediaSessionConnector.setPlayer(player);
    playerNotificationManager.setMediaSessionToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken());

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    playerNotificationManager.setPlayer(player);
    player.release();
    player = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    BookElement book = intent.getParcelableExtra("track");

    mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder().putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION,
            (long) (book.getSoundFile().getDuration() * 1000)).build());

    MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(Uri.parse(book.getSoundFile().getLocation()))
            .setMediaMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder()
                    .setArtworkUri(Uri.parse(book.getThumbnail().getLocation()))
                    .setArtist(book.getAuthor().getName())
                    .setMediaUri(Uri.parse(book.getSoundFile().getLocation()))
                    .setDisplayTitle(book.getTitle())
                    .build())
            .build();
    MediaSource source = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);

    player.prepare(source);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    return START_STICKY;
}}
```

and my cache class

```
public class downloadUtil {
private static Cache cache;
private static DownloadManager downloadManager;

public static synchronized Cache getCache(Context context){
    if (cache==null){
        File cacheDirectory=new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null),"downloads");
        cache=new SimpleCache(cacheDirectory,new NoOpCacheEvictor());
    }
    return cache;
}

public static synchronized DownloadManager getDownloadManager(Context context){
    if (downloadManager==null){
        Executor downloadExecutor = Runnable::run;

        downloadManager =
                new DownloadManager(context,new StandaloneDatabaseProvider(context),getCache(context),
                        new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory(),downloadExecutor);
        downloadManager.setMaxParallelDownloads(3);
    }
    return downloadManager;
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

just use a monochromic small icon in notifications or not use a small icon at all all workout pretty

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks you i did , and it works just fine